# Issues with using substring() to find a pattern

Tags: java

Here's what I'm trying to implement:

"If the strand is:

AACATGTACTACTGGTG

and the snip method is called like this:

snip("CA", "A")

then the resulting new DNAStrandJedi object should represent the
strand "TGT" which is found after the first match of "CA" at index 2
and before the subsequent match of "A" at index 7."

And here's my code:

```
public DNAStrandJedi snip(String startPattern, String endPattern) {

        if (!passedStrand.contains(startPattern)
                || !passedStrand.contains(endPattern)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String snippedString = passedStrand.substring(3, 5);
            return new DNAStrandJedi(snippedString);

        }
    }
```

The strand that I'm trying to snip is: "AGTCAGTACC"
Here I'm printing the results of the snip() method to the console:

```
System.out.println("Snip: " + test.snip("GT", "TA").getStrandString());
```

I should be getting the strand "CAG" but instead I'm just getting CA.

What I'm having trouble with is figuring out the numbers to use as indices to get the snippedString. Would I have to use some sort of for loop here to get the indices of the startPattern and endPattern? Let me know if you find the question confusing and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: what is the `passedStrand`? is that `passedStrand = "AACATGTACTACTGGTG";`?

Comment: It's returning `CA` because you hardcoded `substring(3,5)` in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf to find the indices...

```
} else {
    int start = passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern) + startPattern.length();
    int end = passedStrand.indexOf(endPattern, start);
    String snippedString = passedStrand.substring(start,end);
    return new DNAStrandJedi(snippedString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The String.indexOf() function is what you need.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String, int)

```
if (passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern) > -1 && passedString.indexOf(endPattern, passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern)) > -1)
   return return new DNAStrandJedi(passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern)+startPattern.length,  passedString.indexOf(endPattern, passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern))-1);
else
   return null;
```

(not tested and not optimal, but its something similar)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is written in simple and clear way and it might explain

```
public DNAStrandJedi snip(String startPattern, String endPattern) {
    int sL          = startPattern.length();
    int startIndex  = passedStrand.indexOf(startPattern);
    int endIndex    = passedStrand.indexOf(endPattern, startIndex + sL);

    if ( startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1 ) 
        return null;
    } 

    String snippedString = passedStrand.substring(startIndex+sL, endIndex);
    return new DNAStrandJedi(snippedString);
}
```

For the information of **Java String Functions** you can see at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10228/ext_func.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Actually @vanza appears to have answered your question it's the "substring(3,5)" that is hard coded that is causing the problem.
You reference a "passedStrand" variable, but you don't show how it is initialized...Did you maybe miss something that's related that we need to know to help you solve the problem?